# how to get single image from list of images from firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hey i m working on an application where i have list of image saving in firebase firestore now in my recyclerview i want only single image out of multiple images now when i am trying to retrive data everything is showing except the images how can i get that??

this is how i am trying to set the single image in recyclerview

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WishlistViewholder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(wishlist_models.get(position).getName());
    holder.email.setText(wishlist_models.get(position).getEmail());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(wishlist_models.get(position).getImage())
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.wishlist_image);

}
```

**firebase database**

[image]

model class

public class Wishlist_Model {

```
String image;
String name;
String email;
String delete;
List<String> images;

public Wishlist_Model() {
}

public Wishlist_Model(String image, String name, String email, String delete, List<String> images) {
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.delete = delete;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDelete() {
    return delete;
}

public void setDelete(String delete) {
    this.delete = delete;
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this -**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WishlistViewholder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(wishlist_models.get(position).getName());
    holder.email.setText(wishlist_models.get(position).getEmail());

   if(wishlist_models.get(position).getImage()!=null && wishlist_models.get(position).getImage().size()>0) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(wishlist_models.get(position).getImage().get(0))
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.wishlist_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: brother get(0) method after getImage is not working

Comment: can you please show your model class ?

Comment: please check brother

Comment: It looks proper, What happens After using the above code, Please share errors if any?

Comment: it is saying  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: If Image array is null and null check as well, let me modified ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247753/discussion-between-aditya-nandardhane-and-vivek-m-fauzdar).